# What should I do to change payment methods if changing the configuration has no effects?

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, magento-community, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to configure accepted payment methods on my (first) Magento 2 website. I disabled "Check Money Order" and enabled "Bank transfer" and "Cash on Delivery" payments through the admin panel. However, the checkout page still displays only the Check/Money Order method (which I disabled). I have already:

- flushed/disabled cache
- deleted cached static content and preprocessed views
- looked for conflicting settings in different scopes
- switched back to `Blank` theme from my custom one
- flushed browser cache

Nothing happens with the payment methods.

If it can be useful:

- Magento (v. 2.1.3 CE) is currently in development mode (I don't know if this information may be useful).
- Other than changing the payment methods, I also edited a few settings about taxes to have the catalog show prices with taxes included. This setting has not produced effects as well. I haven't investigated this issue as much as for the payment methods, anyway.

Am I missing any steps?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue. I had been configuring payment methods at website scope (without other settings at view/global scopes). I tried changing settings at global scope and it worked.

I don't know if this is a bug or I am just missing a bit of knowledge about configuration scopes.